# How to rollback a python application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rollback

I am running on Windows 8 and I was recently uploading an application using the standard Google App Engine launcher but it froze mid way and when I closed it and reopened it and tried to upload again it would say a transaction is already in progress for this application and that I would need to rollback the application using appcfg.py.

I looked all over the internet and I understand what to execute, however I don't know how/where.

I tried doing it in the standard Windows command prompt but it just opened the appcfg.py file for me, I tried doing it in the python console but it said is not a valid function, I also tried to run the application locally and access the interactive console but it just said the same thing as the python console attempt.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the windows command prompt, reference your python executable:

eg:

[cmd]

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine (ie: [GAE dir])

C:\Python27\python.exe appcfg.py rollback [deploy dir]